Is there any trick to compute $\log(x)$ accurately when $x$ is close to $1$?
I need to compute the natural logarithm $\log(x)$ with a high relative accuracy, using IEEE754 arithmetic, when $x$ is very close to unity, say $x=1.00000000000001$. Is there any algorithm or trick allowing this?
Of course, in such a case $\log(x)$ is close to $x-1$, which suggests computing $x-1$, but the result is highly inaccurate due to the loss of significant digits in subtraction. Similarly inaccurate is the standard function $\log(x)$. Using $\text{logp1}(x-1)$ is equally inadequate, as the subtraction between $x$ and $1$ is needed again.
I wonder if the following reasoning may explain what happens: If $\delta y/y$ is the relative error of $y=f(x)$ and $\delta x/x$ is the relative error of $x$, then we have a relationship:  $|\delta y/y| = cond(f) |\delta x/x|$ where $cond(f)=|f'(x)x/f(x)|=|1/log(x)|$ in the case of $f(x)=log(x)$. Now, assuming that $|\delta x/x|=10^{-16}$ and $x=1+10^{-15}$, we get $|\delta y/y| = 0.1$. Hence, it seems there is no way to compute the logarithm accurately, independently of which method or algorithm is used. This results from the conditioning of this function.

Did you try looking up the glibc code for IEEE754 doubles? It is not always the clearest, but it can be helpful if you read c.  I can find the link but I'm not sure if you need something that's better than the c standard math library or if you just want to know a method.

Continued fractions often yield very good approximations. I don't know how to use them to do this, but here is what I found.

I think the problem is simply that relative accuracy is the wrong measure to use when very close to zero. It has nothing to do with logarithms per se.

One basic problem you face is that numbers near one cannot be represented with high accuracy in floating point, i.e. you face a problem in representing $x$ even before you try to compute $\log(x)$.  You might consider rephrasing the problem as computing $\log(1 + \epsilon)$ for small $\epsilon$, assuming you have a means for computing $\epsilon$ .

If your input really is 1.00000000000001 stored in a floating point format, then that input simply does not have the precision required to get enough accuracy in the output. That is why it would be better to use logp1 and have as input for example z=1.2345678e-14 which has enough precision. You would not calculate or store x, but only store z. And z is not calculated from x as z=x-1, but instead x is calculated from z as x=z+1. Yes, x=z+1 loses precision, but you never store that or use it in the calculation, but use z instead.

What is "logp1"?

@JaapScherphuis - Looks like it's actually named "log1p". Dominique - It's a pre-existing numpy function that already does exactly what's being asked for.

@JaapScherphuis - That might be worth turning into an answer. From the last part of their question it looks like they're aware of the right function to use, but don't know how to use it.

log1p is also the name of a Python function in math with the same intent.

I am not convinced that the crucial issue is to better represent x, as this would imply an analogous difficulty with other numbers, like for example 2.000000000000001 or 3.000000000000001, but computing log(x) for such numbers is accurate (I believe).

The difference is $\ln(2+\epsilon)\approx\ln2$ is a small relative error.

Please note also that log(1.00000000000001) equals about 0.00000000000001, which itself is not such a small number that it cannot be represented with the machine precision. Hence, I feel that the crucial point is to have a suitable algorithm.

@Leszek If you use a continued fraction approximation, then you are talking about a rational number (two ints, of some size) and in theory I think that means you can use that to convey a lot of precision, but evaluating it as a float would be useless if it the result is going to fall under machine precision.

As presented, it's too late to solve this.
Not every real number is exactly representable as an IEEE754 floating-point number. Those that aren't will be rounded towards the closest representable number. So you can understand a floating-point number as a range of real numbers - the value it actually represents could be infinite possibilities, all you know is it falls somewhere in that range.
For example, taking the 64 bit floating-point number closest to $1.0000000000000002$, or to give its exact value:
$$1.0000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625$$
(just call it $1+2^{-52}$ for short), then it could represent any number in the range $1+2^{-53}$ to $1+3\times2^{-53}$. Numbers a little smaller than that will round down to 1, and numbers a little bigger will round up to $1.0000000000000004$.
So, if you're only interested in the center of that range, then the logarithm of $1+2^{-52}$ is an irrational number which is approximately
$$0.00000000000000022204460492503128343282304546154879259\ldots$$
so pretty close to $2^{-52}$ but not exactly.
But you're not only interested in the center of that range. Your original input, which rounded off to $1.0000000000000002$, might have been as low as $1+2^{-53}$, in which case the above logarithm is wrong by a factor of 2! Or it could be higher, in which case the above logarithm is much too small. How can we fix this?
Well, now, we can't. Because our input was already rounded off, the information we need has been lost.

The solution is to go back to wherever you're getting the values of $x$ from and convince them to store the value of $x-1$ instead.
Floating-point numbers are designed so that their relative accuracy remains more or less constant, while their absolute accuracy changes (very accurate near zero and very innaccurate near infinity). So, close to zero, the representable numbers are closer together, and you'll be able to distinguish between $2^{-52}$ and, say, $1.0000000000000002\times2^{-52}$. That sounds like the kind of accuracy you're looking for.
This may require you to write a new function to compute... whatever it is you were computing minus one. For example, if $x$ was previously the output of some $e^y$ for $y$ close to zero, you'll need to create a way to accurately compute $e^y-1$.

You might know that for $x \in ]-1,1[: \frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{i=0}^{+\infty}x^i$.
By integrating this, you get: $$\ln(1-x) = -\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{i}}{i}$$
This can be used as a basis for approximations.

You should edit your answer to say "for all $x \in (-1,1)$" and  "$-\ln(1-x) = \dots$"

@rafilou2003: thanks for your comment. I've updated my answer accordingly. You can retract your downvote :-)

It wasn't my downvote :)
